# Configuration the postrest with the postgresql database on Heroku or AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, configuration, postgrest

I need help related to the configuration of PostgREST with the PostgreSQL database dumped into Heroku or AWS.

What are the exact steps from the beginning?

Comment: Did you already follow https://postgrest.com/en/v4.3/tutorials/tut0.html?

Comment: I followed but I have an issue. After: create role web_anon nologin;
grant web_anon to postgres; grant usage on schema api to web_anon;
grant select on api.todos to web_anon when I run an app on heroku domain I got error that web_anon role does not exist. Can you suggest something?